# Spinner won't display items (switch situation : different item lists for one and only one spinner - code inside)

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

My application works this way : there is a menu with different buttons ("Category 1", "Category 2", etc.) and all these buttons open the same activity called "ResultListViewActivity", which displays a ListView with content from a database, depending on the button you clicked before.

So there is ONE activity displaying a listview whose content varies. I am trying to add a "filter mode" for this list view. I have a "filter button" opening an alertdialog window, this alert dialog has a spinner inside. I am working on a way to display different content in this spinner, and then to assign different listeners to each item. So for example, if on the main menu you click on "Category 1" button, it sets a variable "filterVariable" to the value 1, if you click "Category 2" it would be to value 2, and so on.
I have written this with a switch attribute but it crashes my app with a pointer null exception. Here is my code:

```
 OnClickListener filter_listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View dialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.alertdialog_filter, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                context);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        int filterVariable = bundle.getInt("filterVariable");

        switch (filterVariable) {

      // if you click on button "category 1" in main menu
        case 1: 
            ArrayAdapter<?> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ResultListViewActivity.this, R.array.spinner_category1, R.id.alertdialog_spinner);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            break;
      // if you click on button "category 2" in main menu        
        case 12: 
            ArrayAdapter<?> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(ResultListViewActivity.this, R.array.spinner_category2, R.id.alertdialog_spinner);
            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter1);

            break;

        }

        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                });


        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // Lorsque l'on cliquera sur annuler on quittera
                        // l'application
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        // set alertdialog_filter.xml to alertdialog builder
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}; }
```

It really drives me crazy, I had managed to do it in the case of a popup menu ( my code is here for those who might be interested: [How to set specific listeners for varying popup menus ? (code inside)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517779/how-to-set-specific-listeners-for-varying-popup-menus-code-inside/15518026?noredirect=1#comment22019174_15518026) ) but now it's not popup menu anymore but spinner, everything is different and what I did for popup menu is of no use.

Comment: Do you initialize the spinner variable?

Comment: Yes I did, I initialized my spinner and found the view by Id.

Comment: Post the stacktrace with the exception and also point in your code the line which is trowing that exception.

Comment: try dialogView.findviewbyid( R.id.alertdialog_spinner);

Comment: I did not quite understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to have a submenu for each menu? If so, are you aware that you can easily do this just using the menu xml? Or are you trying to do some fancy thing?

Comment: What I am trying to do is to display different lists of content from one spinner button. I have 16 kind of contents I can display (for ex: restaurants, resorts, night life places, etc); so I don't want to create 16 activities but only one with the content being modified according to what the user did before. So I would like one spinner being able to display different content in a "switch / case" way. I am gonna try what has been said before, thanks everyone.